# For each CohortGroup assign the Proper CohortPeriod Count

Tags: pandas, numpy

I am trying to assign the proper cohort period count to the 'Cohort Period' column for each cohort group. I believe showing what I am trying to achieve makes more sense.

For loops seem like the way to go, was wondering if the same can be achieved using some nifty pandas function.

```
Out[7]: 
   OrderPeriod CohortGroup  Cohort Period
0     1/1/2017    1/1/2017            NaN
1     1/1/2017    1/1/2017            NaN
2     1/1/2017    1/1/2017            NaN
3     1/1/2017    1/1/2017            NaN
4     1/1/2017    1/1/2017            NaN
5     1/1/2017    1/1/2017            NaN
6     1/1/2017    1/1/2017            NaN
7     1/1/2017    1/1/2017            NaN
8     4/1/2017    1/1/2017            NaN
9     6/1/2017    1/1/2017            NaN
10    8/1/2017    1/1/2017            NaN
11    9/1/2017    1/1/2017            NaN
12    9/1/2017    1/1/2017            NaN
13   11/1/2017    1/1/2017            NaN
14    4/1/2018    1/1/2017            NaN
15    6/1/2018    1/1/2017            NaN
16   12/1/2018    1/1/2017            NaN
17    1/1/2019    1/1/2017            NaN
18    5/1/2019    1/1/2017            NaN
19    2/1/2017    2/1/2017            NaN
20    3/1/2017    3/1/2017            NaN
21    3/1/2017    3/1/2017            NaN
22    3/1/2017    3/1/2017            NaN
23    3/1/2017    3/1/2017            NaN
24    3/1/2017    3/1/2017            NaN
25    4/1/2017    3/1/2017            NaN
```

If Cohort Group and OrderPeriod are the same it's assigned a 1, then counts for each new OrderPeriod and assigns that number to Cohort Period. Once a new CohortGroup starts the process begins again.

```
Out[7]: 
   OrderPeriod CohortGroup  Cohort Period
0     1/1/2017    1/1/2017            1.0
1     1/1/2017    1/1/2017            1.0
2     1/1/2017    1/1/2017            1.0
3     1/1/2017    1/1/2017            1.0
4     1/1/2017    1/1/2017            1.0
5     1/1/2017    1/1/2017            1.0
6     1/1/2017    1/1/2017            1.0
7     1/1/2017    1/1/2017            1.0
8     4/1/2017    1/1/2017            2.0
9     6/1/2017    1/1/2017            3.0
10    8/1/2017    1/1/2017            4.0
11    9/1/2017    1/1/2017            5.0
12    9/1/2017    1/1/2017            5.0
13   11/1/2017    1/1/2017            6.0
14    4/1/2018    1/1/2017            7.0
15    6/1/2018    1/1/2017            8.0
16   12/1/2018    1/1/2017            9.0
17    1/1/2019    1/1/2017           10.0
18    5/1/2019    1/1/2017           11.0
19    2/1/2017    2/1/2017            1.0
20    3/1/2017    3/1/2017            1.0
21    3/1/2017    3/1/2017            1.0
22    3/1/2017    3/1/2017            1.0
23    3/1/2017    3/1/2017            1.0
24    3/1/2017    3/1/2017            1.0
25    4/1/2017    3/1/2017            2.0
```

Comment: Why is `Cohort Period` for row 11 and 12 the same?

Answer (score 2):

First we make your `CohortGroup` groups be checking where it changes with `shift`

Then we use `groupby.apply` to check where `OrderPeriod` is not the same as `CohortGroup`:

```
groups = df['CohortGroup'].ne(df['CohortGroup'].shift()).cumsum()

cohort_period = df.groupby(groups)\
                  .apply(lambda x: (x['OrderPeriod'].ne(x['CohortGroup'])\
                                    & x['OrderPeriod'].ne(x['OrderPeriod'].shift(-1)))\
                         .cumsum().add(1)).values

df['Cohort Period'] = cohort_period
```

**output**

```
   OrderPeriod CohortGroup  Cohort Period
0     1/1/2017    1/1/2017              1
1     1/1/2017    1/1/2017              1
2     1/1/2017    1/1/2017              1
3     1/1/2017    1/1/2017              1
4     1/1/2017    1/1/2017              1
5     1/1/2017    1/1/2017              1
6     1/1/2017    1/1/2017              1
7     1/1/2017    1/1/2017              1
8     4/1/2017    1/1/2017              2
9     6/1/2017    1/1/2017              3
10    8/1/2017    1/1/2017              4
11    9/1/2017    1/1/2017              4
12    9/1/2017    1/1/2017              5
13   11/1/2017    1/1/2017              6
14    4/1/2018    1/1/2017              7
15    6/1/2018    1/1/2017              8
16   12/1/2018    1/1/2017              9
17    1/1/2019    1/1/2017             10
18    5/1/2019    1/1/2017             11
19    2/1/2017    2/1/2017              1
20    3/1/2017    3/1/2017              1
21    3/1/2017    3/1/2017              1
22    3/1/2017    3/1/2017              1
23    3/1/2017    3/1/2017              1
24    3/1/2017    3/1/2017              1
25    4/1/2017    3/1/2017              2
```

Comment: Little off on row 18

Answer (score 2):

I will do `rank`

```
df=df.apply(pd.to_datetime)

df['Cohort Period']=df.groupby('CohortGroup')['OrderPeriod'].rank('dense')
df
   OrderPeriod CohortGroup  Cohort Period
0   2017-01-01  2017-01-01            1.0
1   2017-01-01  2017-01-01            1.0
2   2017-01-01  2017-01-01            1.0
3   2017-01-01  2017-01-01            1.0
4   2017-01-01  2017-01-01            1.0
5   2017-01-01  2017-01-01            1.0
6   2017-01-01  2017-01-01            1.0
7   2017-01-01  2017-01-01            1.0
8   2017-04-01  2017-01-01            2.0
9   2017-06-01  2017-01-01            3.0
10  2017-08-01  2017-01-01            4.0
11  2017-09-01  2017-01-01            5.0
12  2017-09-01  2017-01-01            5.0
13  2017-11-01  2017-01-01            6.0
14  2018-04-01  2017-01-01            7.0
15  2018-06-01  2017-01-01            8.0
16  2018-12-01  2017-01-01            9.0
17  2019-01-01  2017-01-01           10.0
18  2019-05-01  2017-01-01           11.0
19  2017-02-01  2017-02-01            1.0
20  2017-03-01  2017-03-01            1.0
21  2017-03-01  2017-03-01            1.0
22  2017-03-01  2017-03-01            1.0
23  2017-03-01  2017-03-01            1.0
24  2017-03-01  2017-03-01            1.0
25  2017-04-01  2017-03-01            2.0
```

Comment: Reason I made the `groups` variable is: what if `CohortGroup` later changes to `2017-01-01` again?